# How to Get "Save As" option in new generated file using Macro.

Tags: vba, excel

I have complied a code which extract a worksheet from a workbook. 
The problem is the worksheet that gets extracted and get created as new file, gets saved in my documents or in some random location. is there anyway I can get a prompt window  which gives me "Save as" Option ? So I can save it at my desired location?

By searching in this forum I tried two different things,

```
 With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
.Name = "MyTitle"
.Show
```

I also tired

```
App.SendKeys("{F12}")
enter code here
```

But it gave me error.

Here Is my code Can anyone help. I am not sure where exactly I can put it.(there might be some extra unnecessary stuff as I don't know how code works but somehow I am trying to make it work)

```
Sub GetCalcs()

Dim Flname As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next

Flname = "Calculation-" & InputBox("Enter Pump tag No P-XXXX:") & ".xls"
Sheets(Array("Calculations")).Copy

newfilename = Flname

With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs newfilename, FileFormat:=50
.Close 0
End With
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If ws.Name <> "Main Calc" Then
ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End If

Next

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```

Comment: *thumbs up + smile*

Comment: I just realized that it give me pop up window and save as option. But it doesnt save anything to that location or anywhere.

Can you help we how to use it so the new generated file gets saved at desired location ? or do I need to define any variable etc?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to include the path in the filename. Just add a file path to the name of your file and you should be good!

> Flname = {path your want to save to} & "Calculation-" &
>   InputBox("Enter Pump tag No P-XXXX:") & ".xls"

If you want to customize the location you would like to save to each time, then just popup a prompt box.

> With ActiveWorkbook 
>   saveLocation = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter save
>   location:", Title:="Save Location",
>   Default:="C:\Users\User\Documents", Type:=2)
>
> Flname = "Calculation-" & InputBox("Enter Pump tag No P-XXXX:") &
>   ".xls" Sheets(Array("Calculations")).Copy
>
> newfilename = saveLocation & Flname
>
> .SaveAs newfilename, FileFormat:=50 .Close 0 End With For Each ws In
>   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets If ws.Name <> "Main Calc" Then ws.Visible =
>   xlSheetVeryHidden
>
> End If
>
> Next

Comment: No it didn't work 
Sorry May be I have not explained it correctly. 
I am looking for something that will ask me every time where I want to save the file.